# Convert an array of elements to promise and return it out

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, protractor

Here actualLevels array is throwing empty array in the expect line.I need the actualLevels to be populated and returned to assertion only aftr the array is completely populated

Code:

```
var expected = ['Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4'];
var actualLevels=[];

element.all(by.css('somecssid')).each(function(elm) {
    elm.getText().then(function (textValue) {
        console.log(textValue);  // prints texts of the css i.e.Level1
        actualLevels.push(textValue);
    })
}
expect(actualLevels).toBe(expected);  // jasmine expect assertion
```

Comment: Are you using protractor?

Comment: yes I use protractor.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getText()` on the `ElementFinderArray` directly:

```
expect(element.all(by.css('somecssid')).getText()).toEqual(expected);
```

Note that there is no need to resolve the promise manually, in Protractor `expect()` is patched to understand and resolve promises implicitly.

Note 2: `toBe` would check if both variables point to the same exact object - you need `toEqual`.

---

Just FYI, `each()` was not a good choice, [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) would be more appropriate:

```
var expected = ['Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4'];
var actualLevels = element.all(by.css('somecssid')).map(function(elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});
expect(actualLevels).toEqual(expected);  // jasmine expect assertion
```

If you want to additionally log the texts on the console one by one, resolve the `getText()`:

```
var actualLevels = element.all(by.css('somecssid')).map(function(elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
        return text;
    });
});
```

Just FYI 2: you can replace `element.all(by.css('somecssid'))` with a shortcut:

```
$$('somecssid')
```

Comment: why does a log statement before return elm.getText(); prints me the protractor obj info rather than text?

Answer (score 0):

Because your `getText` function is asynchronous, your `expect` on line 10 is called before anything is pushed into `textValue`.

Additionally, the order in which the `textValue` is inserted is not guaranteed to be the same, because each invocation is asynchronous. You could end up with something like `['Level 4', 'Level 2', 'Level 3']`. To fix this, you're going to want to use something like `Promise.map`. You could do something like

`Promise.map(arrayOfThings, function(elm) {
         return elm.getText();
     }).then(function(actualLevels){
         expect(actualLevels).toBe(expected);
     });`

Ideally you would use the optional callback parameter from your testing framework to test this code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in the Jasmine context, but in general the pattern you're looking for is

```
Promise.all(element.map(actualLevel)) . 
  then(actualLevels => console.log(actualLevels));
```